# Amazon S3 Python Bulk File Transfer through Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I want to tranfer files in around 1000 directories to an Amazon S3 bucket using Pythons S3 package.
How could I do it ?

Comment: This question is too general - you could do it in lots of different ways. If you read up the documentation, try it and have a specific problem, then post a question with more specific information.

Answer (score 3):

I like boto,

http://code.google.com/p/boto/